# How to import classes to create TextArea with line numbers in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, import, textarea, richtext, line-numbers

I want to create a TextArea in JavaFX with line numbers.
I think [RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX)  is want I am looking for but I don't know, how to import the classes in Netbeans correctly.

Following lines of code are from the [XMLEditor.java](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX/blob/master/richtextfx-demos/src/main/java/org/fxmisc/richtext/demo/XMLEditor.java) demo:

```
import org.fxmisc.flowless.VirtualizedScrollPane;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.CodeArea;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.LineNumberFactory;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.StyleSpans;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.StyleSpansBuilder;
```

The last four import instructions are from project RichTextFX, and the first is from project Flowless. Is it sufficient to copy those 5 classes to my default package? Or should I download both projects, zip them to JARs and add them as a libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Maven part already explained in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41759703/175554) I think you can also use gradle too all up to your preference. For bringing line numbers to CodeArea example code

```java
// add line numbers to the left of area
codeArea.setParagraphGraphicFactory(LineNumberFactory.get(codeArea));
```

For the full working code example check [here](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX/blob/master/richtextfx-demos/src/main/java/org/fxmisc/richtext/demo/JavaKeywordsDemo.java#L97C9-L98C78). and example look
[image: richtext codearea editor with line numbers]
about what to import is also up to your use. in my project([screenshots](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/swaggerific/issues/4#issuecomment-1604765798)) I use only 2

```java
import org.fxmisc.richtext.CodeArea;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.LineNumberFactory;
```

I don't have "flawless", meaning it is not **mandatory**, the example code they share is just a show for features, you do not need to copy all.

Answer (score -1):

In order to use RichTextFX, you need to add the whole library together with its dependencies. You can use a build tool with dependency management, such as maven, gradle or ant+ivy. Check the [RichTextFX github page](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX) for more details.

If you want to do it manually, the easiest way is probably to download a "fat jar" from the [RichTextFX releases page](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX/releases) and add it to your project. It should include all the dependencies.